# CopyPasteType.ValuesOnly returns blank cell sometimes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that put a randbetween function into a cell and then copy/pastes it with values only.

I have two scripts that work separately, but when I try to combine them into one script it returns a blank cell.

Here is my first script to put the function into the cell. This puts the function into the cell, but the `Values_only` part doesn't seem to do anything as it leaves the function in the cell.

```
function letterDie() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rand = "=index(Scategories!$A$15:$B$41,match(RANDBETWEEN(1,26),Scategories!$A$15:$A$41,0),2)"
  var cell = ss.getRange('E1');
  
  var letter = cell.setValue(rand).copyTo(cell, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);

}
```

Then here is the code I have that copies and pastes the function with values only so that I am left with just the random letter. This code also works fine.

```
function copyPaste() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

I can run the first and then the second and it works fine, but when I try to combine them into one function, the cell is blank.

I have even tried creating a function to call the first, then the second but it still returns a blank cell.

```
function rollDie() {
  
  letterDie();
  copyPaste();
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that both functions are making changes to the spreadsheet file and these changes **depend on each other**. Namely, `letterDie()` **sets** the value of cell **E1** and `copyPaste()` **gets** that value.

Try to [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) the pending changes between the executions of the two functions:

```
function rollDie() {
  
  letterDie();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  copyPaste();
  
}
```